# How does the GAN based prediction in K. Zhang et al. (2018) improve performance?

Tags: deep-learning, gan, finance

In [Stock Market Prediction Based on Generative Adversarial](https://reader.elsevier.com/reader/sd/pii/S1877050919302789?token=D090EAD19CF85BFC09182ED29BD8ACCE2B740999F47433B116BE749DDFCE2C226CEB6132FACAD0FA8CE05F760EA3F85E) Network by K. Zhang et. al, the authors feed financial data (X<sub>0</sub>...X<sub>t</sub>) into an LSTM to predict X<sub>t+1</sub>.

Then, they evaluate whether the series (X<sub>0</sub>...X<sub>t+1</sub>) is real or not (with as X<sub>t+1</sub> either the predicted or the one appearing in the data).

This is done in a GAN system, with the predictor trained to create an X<sub>t+1</sub> so that the series would fool the discriminator.

What is the benefit of training the predictor as a generator in GAN, with the discriminator in providing the loss function, when it would be simpler to use a loss based on |predX<sub>t+1</sub> - X<sub>t+1</sub>| ?

After all, the aim is to predict the target values - so why not train using the fit of the prediction directly?